# Trigger on a field is fired unexpectedly when I update another field

Tags: mysql, triggers

Here is my table:

```
Id    Password       Status
1     a6cc890..       1
```

I have a trigger upon Password which is used to encrypt the field.

The trigger is as below:

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

USE `ediftpdb`$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`edidbo`@`%`
TRIGGER `ediftpdb`.`trigger_format_passwd`
BEFORE INSERT ON `ediftpdb`.`users`
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.passwd=md5(NEW.passwd)$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`edidbo`@`%`
TRIGGER `ediftpdb`.`trigger_format_passwd_update`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `ediftpdb`.`users`
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.passwd=md5(NEW.passwd)$$
```

To my surprise, the trigger is fired when I update Status, and the password is encrypted again!

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update `Status`, you're doing an UPDATE and all of the UPDATE triggers will fire. All you need to do is compare the new and old values of `passwd` and only apply your MD5 if they are different. Lucky for you, MySQL supplies [`OLD` and `NEW` row aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html):

> You can refer to columns in the subject table (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases `OLD` and `NEW`. `OLD.col_name` refers to a column of an existing row before it is updated or deleted. `NEW.col_name` refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated. Try using [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
BEFORE UPDATE ON `ediftpdb`.`users`
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.passwd = IF(NEW.passwd = OLD.passwd, NEW.passwd, md5(NEW.passwd))
```

This shouldn't change `NEW.passwd` unless `NEW.passwd` (the new password) and `OLD.passwd` (the hashed password that is already in the database) are different. Of course, this might fail if someone manages to enter the MD5 of their old password as their new password but that's pretty unlikely.

Comment: So, `BEFORE UPDATE ON \`table\`.\`field\`` is synonymous with `BEFORE UPDATE ON \`table\``?

Comment: Oh, `users` is the table. Right, well the trigger's doing exactly what it's told to ..

Comment: @Tomalak: Right, got lost in the backticks, eh? I'd like to thrash the MySQL people roughly about the face and neck for choosing backticks for quoting, just makes an unreadable mess IMO. MySQL doesn't have column level triggers.

Comment: Nah, I'm just not used to seeing `\`a\`.\`b\`` where `a` and `b` are database and table (rather than table and column) respectively. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you "update `Status`", you're actually performing an `UPDATE` on the whole table. The fact that you only modify the value of one field doesn't come into it!

You can manually check whether the value of `passwd` has changed using [the `NEW` and `OLD` identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html).